# Finding every nth element in a list in dart

Tags: dart

I have a list of lists

```
List<List<double>> data = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3], [2,2,3], [2,2,3], [1,2,3],  ...];
```

I need to put the first element in the inner arrays in an array;

so result will be

```
<List<double> newData  = [1,1,2,2,1.....]
```

Comment: Minimal examples: `List<T> elementsAt<T>(int index, List<List<T>> lists) => [for (var list in lists) list[index]];`. Can also be written as extension `extension ListLists<T> on List<List<T>> { List<T> elementsAt(int index) => [for (var list in this) list[index]]; }`. Or you can choose to create an iterable instead: `Iterable<T> elementsAt<T>(int index, List<List<T>> lists) sync* { for (var list in lists) yield list[index] }`. Heck, can even do `Iterable<T> elementsAt(int index, Iterable<Iterable<T>> lists) sync* { for (var list in lists) yield list.elementAt(index); }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just the first element for each inner list, or you want one element in particular, try this.

```dart
  final data = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
  ];

  final newData = [...data.map((e) => e.first)];  // or elementAt(...)
  print(newData); // [1, 4]
```

If you want *every* element in that array (column-like), then I'll just try and brute force as follows (I'm sure there are better ways to do this with `package:collection`, but I'm unsure how atm).

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

  const columnsAmount = 3;
  final data = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
  ];

  final result = <int, List<int>>{
    for (var i = 0; i < columnsAmount; i++) i: []
  };
  for (final d in data) {
    d.forEachIndexed((index, element) {
      result[index]?.add(element);
    });
  }

  print(result);  // {0: [1, 4], 1: [2, 5], 2: [3, 6]}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for the first (and last) index in the array. But what the second for example... Sorry example a bit misleading.

Comment: Oh, you've asked for the first element in your question. Then, I'll edit my question

Comment: There you go. Let me know if it helped and, eventually, accept the answer if it actually answered your question